# Huawei HG8245T Router - not connecting to another router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, modem

I just got a fiber optic connection installed at home and due to the build of the house, it's mostly cement/bricks, the wireless connection isn't received throughout the house. Previously, to combat this issue, I just ran a hardwire from the modem downstairs and upstairs and had it connected to a secondary (DLink) router. It did the job of getting me seamless wireless internet access everywhere.

The issue is now with the new Huawei router, this setup isn't working. I have connected everything as previously, but it seems that the other (DLink) routers are not picking up the connection. I have tried everything and am totally lost as what to do to overcome this problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "connected everything as previously" - Care to share with us exactly how it was/is setup?  "it seems that the other (DLink) routers are not picking up the connection" not sure what this means, can you expand on exactly what you mean by "connection"?  "I have tried everything" -- Please share with us what you've tried already, and what the results were.  Without this information this is pretty hard, if not impossible, to answer.

Answer (score 0):

When adding an additional router to your network you can do the same setup (ethernet cable to add the additional router) but, don't forget, you need to set the new router to have a reserved address on the new Huawei router that is outside of your DHCP scope (but within the subnet range) and set the "extender" router to be in "Access Point" mode, You will also need to set the "extender" router's default gateway IP to be the huawei router's LAN address... You'll also need to configure the access point's SSID, channel, encryption type and passphrase the same as the Huawei router to provide seamless connectivity between devices...